# How to redirect VPN traffic on OS X

Tags: routing, mac-osx, mac-osx-server, route

I have following problem: I need to connect to VPN and access specific resources (ip addresses). When I connect to VPN all network traffic goes through VPN but in fact I need only specific destinations to be accessed over VPN and the rest of the traffic to go through default route and avoid VPN.

Here is the result of `netstat -nr`

Before I connect to VPN:

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGScI          19        0     en1
```

After I connect to VPN:

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.1.1.1        UGSc          123     3744    jnc0
default            192.168.0.1        UGScI          19        0     en1
```

So as you can see I have 2 **default** routes after VPN connected.
All internet traffic goes through the first **default** route which is undesirable behaviour.

Is there a way to set priority for the default route? So all traffic by default doesn't go through VPN but only manually created routes redirect to VPN i.e. `sudo route -n add 172.0.0.1 10.1.1.1`

Comment: Talk with your VPN provider and ask them to enable split tunnelling.

Comment: It seems it is enabled because under ubuntu I have a script which creates appropriate routes and set priority to custom split route table but I am not sure how to do this on OS X. If interested take a look at  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217700/how-to-set-up-routing-tables-on-os-x-to-redirect-vpn-traffic

Comment: Please provide details on the VPN server configuration.

Comment: Are you using L2TP VPN configured in the OS X Network System Preferences? If so, have you verified that if you go to  > System Preferences > Network > select your VPN interface on the left pane > Advanced... > Options > deselect the "Send all traffic over VPN connection" option?

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/247135/force-juniper-network-client-to-use-split-routing

Comment: I am using Juniper client to connect to VPN network

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can delete the default route (for the VPN) and then set up new route(s) for only those networks/address that you want to get routed through the VPN.  Use sudo route delete to delete routes.