# How to set route table priority on OS X

Tags: routing, mac-osx, mac-osx-server, route

Is it possible to set route table priority or metric?
On Ubuntu I can run following commands to achieve what I want, but I can't find alternative for OS X

```
sudo ip rule add from all lookup $ROUTE_TABLE_NAME prio 1000
sudo ip route add default via $ROUTER_IP dev $LOCAL_IFACE metric 0  table $ROUTE_TABLE_NAME
sudo ip route add default via $VPN_IP dev $VPN_IFACE metric 1  table $ROUTE_TABLE_NAME
```

I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You're ignoring my comment on [your other question](http://serverfault.com/questions/739830/how-to-redirect-vpn-traffic-on-os-x). Please provide details of your VPN server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

The effect you are after can be had with the route command using the -hopcount value.

```
route add -net 1.2.3.0 123.123.123.123 0.0.0.0 -hopcount 4
```

The larger a hopcount, the lower the priority.

Hopcount is indicating the number of steps or routers that traffic must pass through to reach a destination.  All unix systems will choose the lower hopcount by default.

You can also look at adding the -lock modifier to lock the hopcount in.

> man route

for more information