# Access the internet directly while connected to VPN

Tags: vpn, split-tunnel

I'm using Pulse Secure on a Mac OS. When I connect to my company VPN I can access their servers but can't access any external website.

Is it possible to tinker with the VPN client to have access to both internet and local servers?

I've been searching around for info on VPN split tunneling and modifying the routing tables but now I feel stuck. Is there a solution that can be applied on the client side regardless of the VPN client?

Comment: You need to discuss this with your IT department. Most likely this behaviour is by design for security reasons.f you try to circumvent it, you are breaking the policy, which likely is against your employment contract.

Comment: 1) vpn to connect to the company: to me, it seems fitting the "business environment" s.o. policy. 2) "breaking his IT policies" : what do we know about ? please here let stay focused on the technical problem, no digressions, we are not on "advocacy.so.com"...

Comment: We do know that if the pulse client is not permitted to use a split tunnel, it is because the VPN administrators configured it to be that way. Pulse definitely does support split tunnel, but it is not controlled on the client side. Also, this is a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/247135/force-juniper-network-client-to-use-split-routing